# c# как изменять состояния checkbox в коллекции

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<DataGrid x:Name="opened_files_dg" Grid.Row="1"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            IsReadOnly="True" 
            Margin="0,5,0,0" 
          
          >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding  Path = chk , Mode = TwoWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Название" Binding="{Binding Title}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Длина" Binding="{Binding Duration}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Качество" Binding="{Binding Bitrate}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Прогресс" Binding="{Binding Progress}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

public class Song
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public string Bitrate { get; set; }
    public int Progress { get; set; }
    public bool chk { get; set; }

}

songs = new ObservableCollection<Song>();

if(openfilesDialog.ShowDialog()==true){
  
  foreach (var f in openfilesDialog.FileNames){
    Song song = new Song() {
        Title=f,
        Duration="00:00:00",
        Bitrate="128kb/s",
        chk=false
    };
    songs.Add(song);
  }
  opened_files_dg.ItemsSource = songs;
}
```

songs заполняется списком открытых mp3 файлов. не могу получить список отмеченных, не обновляется коллекция

//это просто кнопка для получения списка отмеченных

```
private void go(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string str= "";
    foreach(Song s in songs)
    {
        str += s.chk + "\n";
    }
    test_txt.Text = str;
}
```

выводит false у всех элементов

Comment: На сайте уже 6 лет, куча вопросов, неужели так и не поняли, что в ваших интересах как можно больше информации предоставить сообществу? Вот что это за `chk`, а что внутри `Song`? Как идет привязка контрола? Где эта `songs = new ObservableCollection<Song>();` вызывается? Ну и так далее. Видите, как много информации мне приходится додумывать и "выдирать" у вас силой, почему сразу нельзя написать как положено я не пойму? Не зря ведь придумана такая вещь, как "Минимальный самодостаточный пример".  Ну а так, ответ скорей всего банальный, либо INPC, либо вы перетираете привязку через `= new()`.

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1177075/373567

Comment: @EvgeniyZ , дополнил, можете помочь?

Comment: @axmed2004 Сколько раз вызывается `songs = new ObservableCollection<Song>();`? И очень сильно советую понять основу привязок, это прям основа основ WPF проекта, сейчас у вас просто каша из событий и прочих приблуд.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ 1 раз при открытии файлов в окне

Comment: Еще раз повторю про нормальную привязку, научитесь, очень сильно советую. А так: Я не пойму зачем вы делаете свою кастомную ячейку, когда есть `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`, используйте его (`<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding chk, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />`). Далее, почему у вас стоит `ReadOnly`, если вы пытаетесь изменить свойство класса? Уберите это, а на все колонки, которые не хотите редактировать, поставьте `IsReadOnly="True"`. Собственно вот вам два изменения, которые приводят в порядок вашу таблицу.