# Добавление кнопки в ListView c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

нужно добавить кнопку в элемент listView, которая будет меняться в зависимости от значения в json файле.

Как выглядит структура listView:
[image: галочки и есть кнопки]

В данном случае галочки и есть те самые кнопки. Аккаунты подгружаются при старте приложения из файла json в котором имеется еще значение для каждого аккаунта 'in' которое может быть "yes" или "no".

Я сделал колонки след. образом:

```
<ListView x:Name="AccList">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Number}">№</GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="action" Width="60">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button x:Name="action_button" Width="20" Height="20" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Account}" Width="100" >account</GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

А добавляю элементы так:

```
AccList.Items.Add(new MyItem { Number = i, Account = element.login });
```

На всякий случай еще класс:

```
public class MyItem
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }

        public string Account { get; set; }
    }
```

А теперь к самому вопросу. Мне нужно, что бы в зависимости от значения "in" менялась галочка на крестик (in = "yes" значит галочка, in = "no" значит крестик). В данном случае у меня кнопки проставляются автоматом, поэтому поменять стиль у меня не получается. В голове есть мысль добавлять кнопку программно, но как это сделать, я не нашел.

Буду рад любым подсказкам и решениям, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Триггеры вам в помощь, самый стандартный механизм XAML...

Comment: `DataTrigger` в стиль, и готово. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1177075/373567 еще вот такое есть